# Dependency injection :-An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'controller'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

The controller :

```
private readonly IService _service;

public DisplayController(IService service)
{
    _service = service;
}

public ActionResult Index(int resultid)
{

    var response = _service.GetQuizResults(resultid);

    var alltheresults = Mapper.Map<Services.Contracts.Model.Quiz, Quiz>(response);

    return View(alltheresults);
}
```

Error:

> InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type
>   'Travelers.eBusiness.RiskQuiz.Web.Controllers.DisplayController'. Make
>   sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

After a lot of googling I did add another constructor :

```
public DisplayController()
{

}
```

It did resolve the error, but `_service` becomes null.

Comment: have you added the controller factory?

Comment: Have you followed http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection to initialize the dependency injection and added the instruction how to initialize `IService`?

Comment: Please show your unity configuration code if you want concrete answer. Otherwise generic [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29614042/477420) is best you can get. Note that this problem is very common and searching for existing questions may be better way of solving.

Comment: I suggest you install one of the unity.mvc nuget packages https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Unity can't find a registered implementation of `IService` and therefore can't create an instance of the controller. It can of course create one using the parameter-less constructor you just added, but then it won't inject an instance of `IService`.

You have to register the implementation of `IService` it at application start-up and remove the parameter-less constructor.

See: [setting up the Unity container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx).